# ar: not keeping file modification times

Tags: c++, unix-ar

I have a docker instance running Ubuntu 16.4 LTS. I'm doing C++ builds and using ar/ranlib to produce my .a files. This is losing file modification times.

This is my Makefile rule to manage the archive file:

```
${LIB}: ${LIB_OBJ}
    ar -cvr ${LIB} ${LIB_OBJ}
    ranlib ${LIB}
```

And a little output afterwards:

```
^ ar tv libmylib.a
rw-r--r-- 0/0 129000 Jan  1 00:00 1970 XMLStringWriter.o
rw-r--r-- 0/0  99664 Jan  1 00:00 1970 FileUtilities.o
...

^ ar --version
GNU ar (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
^ ranlib --version
GNU ranlib (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.26.1
```

The system time is correct, and the .o files have proper update times. Furthermore, I do the same build for running on Mac, and the resulting libmylib-mac.a has proper update times with the exact same Makefile, just a different LIB target.

This isn't causing any real problems, but it's annoying. I don't see options to use to the ar command, and a web search didn't find an obvious discussion.

Solutions?

Also, should I eliminate the ranlib command and add the -s (lower case s) option to force a symbol table build?

Comment: Are your filesystems maybe mounted with the "noatime" or "relatime" options and atime is what `ar` is using?  Just a wild guess in the dark..

Comment: @JesperJuhl I would consider that horrible behavior on the part of the ar command.  I did ls -l --time=atime, and the times seem reasonable.

Comment: As I said, it was just a guess. A shot in the dark 

Comment: @JesperJuhl it was worth checking. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu has this fantastic idea that it is a good idea to make the `-D` option the default for `ar`.  AFAICS, it is a complete nuisance, breaking 40+ years of Unix history for something that brings no benefit to me — it is very annoying.

The `-D` option is for 'deterministic' mode and makes the UID, GID and modification time of the files in the archive all 0 (and it uses consistent file modes on all files).  The alternative is `-U` for 'do not operate in deterministic mode'.  There doesn't seem to be an environment variable or similar that can be set to choose between the modes.

Actually, it probably isn't just Ubuntu — see the Linux manual for [`ar(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ar.1.html) for a description.  However, the Linux manual mentions:

> If binutils was configured with `--enable-deterministic-archives`,
>              then this mode is on by default.  It can be disabled with the `U`
>              modifier, below.

In fact, the Ubuntu manual has the same words, but Ubuntu has chosen to make it the default — a decision which I think is unhelpful and counter-productive.

Comment: Oh, that was as un-obvious as it could have been, but it worked. Thank you!     ar -cvrU ${LIB} ${LIB_OBJ}

Comment: As you can tell, @JosephLarson, I found out the hard way and wasn't delighted by finding it out.  I'm happy to relay the news to those who run into it.  The idea is that you will always build the whole library or none of the library, but when I run make, it thinks that the object files in the library are all out of date w.r.t the source code, so it always rebuilds the entire library.  I do not like that very much.  Maybe it benefits distributions; I don't think it benefits most users of distributions, though — I now have to have different flags for `ar` on Ubuntu versus everywhere else. Grump!

Comment: I'd much rather have a consistent result than file mod times _inside_ an archive. What do you use those times for?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit — `make` uses the time stamp in the archive to know whether that member of the archive is up to date with its source.  With “deterministic” archives, the object file in the archive is always out of date, so the whole archive always needs rebuilding, subverting what `make` was designed to do — avoiding unnecessary recompilation.  Clearly it must suit someone.  But it infuriates me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, that makes sense :) For some reason I imagined make would compare the archive's own time with the times of its dependants